# Symfony - Changes in parameters.yml not adopted on production server

Tags: apache2, symfony

After changing a value (`application_domain`) in my `app/config/parameters.yml` file, the webserver still uses the old value that was there before the change.
I am using Symfony 3. The application runs on an Ubuntu server with Apache2.

**app/config/parameters.yml:**

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    application_domain: mydomainname.com
    #other parameters ...
```

Restarting the server and restarting the apache2 service, as well as the `php bin/console cache:clear` command didn't help.

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: @Rooneyl yes, sorry forgot to write that

Comment: obviously you clear the cache with the env parameters

Comment: @Matteo yes, thanks, also just found this out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to add the `--env=prod` option to the php bin/console cache:clear command.
I used `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`.